# How to ask for input until valid letters (A,B,C,or D) are given?

Tags: python, validation, user-input

I need help with my if/else statement for a Marvel character questionnaire.

I want to make sure the user can't enter any letters besides A,B,C or D.

```
if str(input())) not ('A','B','C','D')
else ("ask them again");
```

How do I add `while` to make the code ask for input again if no valid answer was given?

Comment: [**The official python tutorial**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 2):

```
answer = ""
possibleAnswers = {"A","B","C","D"}

while answer not in possibleAnswers:
    answer = input(f"Type a letter, one of {','.join(possibleAnswers)}:")
```

Comment: Thanks alot I appreciate the help.

Comment: A set of valid options is good-practice to compare input (unique, fast, readable). A set variable can also be used to show the user valid options when prompting for input.

Answer (score 1):

One simple option is check each letter:

```
choice='f'
while choice!='A' and choice!='B' and choice!='C' and choice!='D':
  choice=input('Enter letter')
```

if you want to check regardless of case use `.upper()` right after the `input(..)`

Comment: Thank you sir I appreciate the help.